# Why does $m = 40?

Tags: php, operators, addition

Why does $m = 40 on this? I am new in php and I get why $k = 40 , but I cant figure out why $m = 40 as well.

```
<?php
$i = 29;
$j = 11;
$m = 10;

$k = $i++ + $j--;
echo "k = ".$k."<br>";

$j = ($j - 4) / 2;
$m += $j * 10;
echo "m = ".$m."<br>";
?>
```

Comment: Are you wondering what `+=` does? Because the other math is rather trivial (compared to `$i++ + $j--`, which you said you understand).

Comment: I was confused about the +=, was not sure how that made $m = 40. But i think i got got it now. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: $j-- makes $j 10, $j = ($j - 4) / 2 makes $j 3, $m += 3 * 10  = 40...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$j = ($j - 4) / 2; // $j is equal with 10 because of decrement $j-- before
$m += $j * 10; // after that line, $j becomes (10-4)/2 which is 3
echo "m = ".$m."<br>"; // and finally $m = $m + ($j * 10) => 10 + (3 * 10)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I think I'm good with this now. I'm sure you will here from me again.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$i = 29;
$j = 11;
$m = 10;

$k = $i++ + $j--;
// $j == 10
echo "k = ".$k."<br>";

$j = ($j - 4) / 2;
// $j = (10 - 4 ) / 2 == 3
// $m == 10
$m += $j * 10;
// $m + $j * 10 = 10 + 3 * 10 == 40
echo "m = ".$m."<br>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I understand this better now.  In the last part of the code $j which is 3 gets multiplied by 10 for a total of 30 and then $m which is 10 gets added bringing the grand total to 40.

Answer (score 1):

fast explaination of what's happening:

```
$k = 29 + 11 = 40;
$i = 30 (++)
$j = 10 (--)
echo K = 40
$j = (10-4) / 2 = 3
$m = 3 * 10 + 10 = 40
```

the '+=' operator add the results of the operation on the right ($j * 10) to the value on the left ($m that contains 10)

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
$i = 29;
$j = 11;
$m = 10;

$k = $i++ + $j--;

// $k = 40
// $i = 30
// $j = 10

echo "k = ".$k."<br>";

//echo k = 30

$j = ($j - 4) / 2;

// $j = 3

$m += $j * 10;

// $m = 10 + ( 3 * 10 ) = 40

echo "m = ".$m."<br>";

//echo m = 40
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I think I'm good with this now.

Answer (score 1):

**It's probably the $++ and ++$ the puzzles you.**

```
// First try:
$a = 0;
$b = 1;
var_dump($c = $a + $b++); // means: $c = $a + $b; $b = $b + 1;

// Second try:
$a = 0;
$b = 1;
var_dump($c = $a + ++$b); // means: $b = $b + 1; $c = $a + $b;
```

^ make sense?